# One column max to the left and one in the container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with bootstrap grid
I have something like this:
[image]

I would like to get something like this:

where picture is align max to the left of window and second column is in container
[image]

```
<div class="section three">
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-center ">
                    <div class="col-sm">
                            <img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/a
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm">
                            <div class="my-auto"><h2>Lorem ipsum</h2> dolor sit amet,
                    </div>  
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you can achieve this by using the picture in background and col-md-6 col-md-offset-6 so the right content will start from half of the width.

Comment: Yes I know. But then can't break columns without unnecessary css code

Answer (score 0):

Use '.container-fluid' to utilize the full width of the view port. check the documentation here. 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/

Note: since the `<div class="container">` is wrapped by another element `<div class="section three">`, the css properties of `.container` can be effected by this wrapping parent. I hope the above document will help you.